# How to sort column index python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

In python, I am trying to sort my column

```
Index(['id', 'Q1', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12', 'Q13', 'Q14', 'Q15', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4',
       'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9'],
      dtype='object')
```

using

```
**test.sort_index(axis=1,key=lambda x: x.str[1:])**
```

but I am getting results as

Q1  Q10 Q11 Q12 Q13 Q14 Q15 Q2  Q3  Q4  Q5  Q6  Q7  Q8  Q9  id

whereas output should look like:

id,'Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4', 'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9', 'Q10', 'Q11',
'Q12', 'Q13', 'Q14', 'Q15'

Comment: This is a good question: In many languages (including `python`), the `string` of `10` comes **before** `9`. the reason is that string values are defined by asci and the first character in 10 (which is 1) precedes 9. If they were converted from `strings` to `numbers`, then this would suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `Q` by [`str.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and convert values to numeric by [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with converting to `NaN` if non numeric column like `id` and also add `na_position='first'` for first non `Q` columns:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(columns=['id', 'Q1', 'Q10', 'Q11', 'Q12', 'Q13',
                              'Q14', 'Q15', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4','Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7', 'Q8', 'Q9'],)


df = test.sort_index(axis=1,
                     key=lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x.str.replace('Q','',regex=True),errors='coerce'), 
                     na_position='first')
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [id, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, Q6, Q7, Q8, Q9, Q10, Q11, Q12, Q13, Q14, Q15]
Index: []
```

Comment: it shows TypeError: Cannot cast Index to dtype int32

Comment: @harshitkhandelwal - You are right, answer was edited.